# Unity Можно ли получить объект по значению компонента (скрипта)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется префаб, на котором висит скрипт с генерацией id для каждого созданного объекта. При запуске сцены генерируется 20 объектов с id (1,2,3...20).
Цель: получить конкретный объект по id (со скрипта). Это нужно для удаления.
Вопрос: можно ли это сделать, если да, то как? C#

Answer (score 4):

В скрипте иметь словарь, где ключом будет идентификатор, а значением — сгенерированный объект.

```
Dictionary<int, GameObject> myObjects;
```

При инстанциировании складываем туда

```
var myObj = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(2.0f, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
myObjects.Add(1, myObj);
```

Далее когда нужно удалить по id, то обратится к словарю и удалить его оттуда и со сцены.

```
var objToRemove = myObjects[1];
dic.RemoveAt(1);
Destroy(objToRemove);
```

Вроде как-то так.

Answer (score -1):

Если у тебя есть инстанс скрипта то

```
instance.gameObject.Destroy();
```

Так же можешь сделать public static List с твоими обьектами. А внутри обьекта уже иметь айдишник.

Тогда достаточно просто найти в этом листе через Linq обьект с нужным айдишником и его дестройнуть.

Делать же это через какой-то внешний дикшинари -- это как-то костыльно, потому не советую. Костылно потому, как хранить параметр обьекта вне обьекта -- нелогично с точки зрения ООП.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53086/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-unity-------).